# Possible to initialize Parse API with PHP sdk and save objects with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, parse-platform

PHP isn't my strength, but I want to initialize a Parse App with the PHP sdk for extra security, then pass those credentials securely to javascript without revealing the API key and token. Is that possible?

I've tried approaches like this, but to no avail:

```
// Initialize with PHP
<?php
    require 'autoload.php';
    use Parse\ParseClient;
    ParseClient::initialize(MY CREDENTIALS HERE);

    // https://github.com/parseplatform/parse-php-sdk
    $newUser = new ParseObject("TestObject");
?>
```

Then include the javascript SDK and take things over with Javascript...

```
var user = "<?php echo $newUser ?>";
user.save({
    name: "John",
    email: "email@email.com",
    zipcode: "12345"
}).then(function(object) {
  alert("yay! it worked");
  console.log(object);
});
```

Comment: If you run it through php, would need all your own ajax methods.

Comment: @charlietfl, indeed you are right. Time to study up on my ajax. Thanks!